# merge list of files using a loop (bash)

Tags: bash, loops, merge, cat

I am working in bash (Fedora). 
I have a list of text files as follows:

```
filenameA   filename1
filenameA   filename2
filenameA   filename3
filenameB   filename4
filenameB   filename5
```

I wish to combine (cat) all of the files listed in second column with their match in the first column like this:

```
cat filenameA filename1 filename2 filename3  > newfilenameA 
cat filenameB filename4 filename5 > newfilenameB
```

Is there a 'while' or 'for' loop that can accomplish this for a longer list of files?
I want the file contents to be combined, not just a list of file names.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest that you used awk:

```
awk '{a[$1]=a[$1] OFS $2}END{for(i in a)system("cat " i OFS a[i] " >new" i)}' file
```

The first block groups the entries based on the value of the second column. The entries are separated by `OFS`, the Output Field Separator, which is a space by default.

In the `END` block, once all of the lines in the file have been processed, the loop goes through each element of `a`, using `system` to run `cat` in the shell. In awk, strings are concatenated by default, so the command string can be built by joining together the array key `i` and the value `a[i]`. The output of `cat` is redirected to a file, the name of which is obtained by prefixing the input file name with "new".

Comment: I was unclear re. desired output.  I wish for file contents to be combined.  The solution above gives me a new file with "filename filename" but not the file contents. Thanks!

Comment: The code in the edit gave me - awk cmd syntax error - "unterminated string" at the final quote.  I think it is missing a quote.

Comment: It runs perfectly, except I have to ctrl-c to end the hangup at the end.

Comment: That's probably because there are some blank lines in your input. It would be possible to work around this if necessary, either by adding in a check into the script or removing the blank lines.